# LES CSS :not nested pseudo selector issue

Tags: css, less

I ran into a little problem compiling less css:

```
.root {
   .element {
     background: red;

     &-checked:not(&-disabled) {
       color: red;
     }
   }
}
```

Compiles into

```
.root .element {
  background: red;
}
.root .element-checked:not(.root .element-disabled) { <--- THE PROBLEM IS HERE
  color: red;
}
```

But I need it to look like this:

```
.root .element-checked:not(.element-disabled) <--- WITHOUT ROOT IN ':NOT' PSEUDO SELECTOR
```

Is there any way to tell the compiler not to inherit parent selectors?

Thank you!

Comment: You would have to make it a variable and use it like that or instead of element-xxx, just use xxx class. Makes it simpler and easier to write or you could take element out of root if you really want to write it like that. I feel like what you are trying to do is a little overkill with LESS

Comment: I recommend not writing the child class at all but make .element a separate parent class outside .root.

Comment: why not simply making `checked` and `disabled` classes alone? I don't see why you need to do `èlement-*`. It's not realy sclable and flexible